# Making router redirect upon receiving false from authGuard's canActivate

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have multiple authentication guards setup and use them in canActivate. Normally I have had `router.navigate(["/error",403])` in guard itself, but I have started combining different guards so for example i have guard A and guard B in some component i use A some use B and som use logical A OR B. this makes routing from inside guard unusable, when guard returns false routing doesn't do anything. Can I make angular router redirect to my `/error/403` page upon returning false from my guards? I've heard that setting up wildcard to 403 works but I haven't seen any change after setting it up. From what it seems if guard returns false angular doesn't do anything, i don't get any console message and page doesn't redirect anywhere. How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

You can always extend your guards and return an `UrlTree`. So any shared logic goes in your abstract class:

```
export class GuardA extends Guard403 implements CanActivate {
  contructor(router: Router) {
    super(router);
  }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    return this.canThisReallyActivateA().pipe(
      map((canActivate) => canActivate || this.cantActivate;
    )
  }
}

export class GuardB extends Guard403 implements CanActivate {
  contructor(router: Router) {
    super(router);
  }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    return this.canThisReallyActivateB().pipe(
      map((canActivate) => canActivate || this.cantActivate;
    )
  }
}

export abstract class Guard403 {
  readonly cantActivate = this.router.createUrlTree(['/errror', '403']);

  constructor(protected router: Router) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`canActivate` can return, besides `true` / `false`, an `UrlTree`:

```
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree {
    return someTest(snapshot) ? true : this.router.createUrlTree(['/', 'error', '403']);
  }
```